# 500 error when passing variables to function

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the below function in my WordPress functions file, and if I run it as below without the two parameters it works fine, but when I pass the parameters the error handler in the jQuery returns status 500.

If I don't pass the parameters to the PHP function I get status 200 from jQuery, but it's coming from the error handler, and not from the success handler. Why so?

```
function subscribe_funk(){//$payment_method, $customer_handle){
    return "This is a test";
    die();
}
```

It gets called from this ajax:

```
function subscribe(data) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: PT_Ajax.ajaxurl,
            type: "POST",
            data: {'action': 'subscribe_funk', 'payment_method': data.payment_method, 'customer_handle': data.customer},
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function(){
                console.log('Before send subscribe');
            },
            complete: function(){
            },
            success: function (response) { 
                console.log('Message from success handler: ');
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error){
                console.log("Message from error handler:")
                var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
                console.log(errorMessage);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: HTTP 500 -> look into webserver error log, it should contain a hint..

Comment: I don't see anything related in the error_log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function expects 2 parameters, however WP/ajax is not passing them directly.
You need to fetch them from $_POST array yourself:

```
function subscribe_funk(){
    $payment_method = $_POST['payment_method'];
    $customer_handle = $_POST['customer_handle'];
    return "This is a test";
    die();
}
```

Also, you may want to [sanitize the post data](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/data-sanitization-escaping/) with `sanitize_text_field()` or similar function.

Here is a relevant thread in WP StackExchange: [how to pass parameters from jQuery ajax to a PHP function](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/329629/how-to-pass-parameters-from-jquery-ajax-into-php-function)

Comment: Thanks. I still don't understand why I'm not getting a result from the succes handler?

Comment: Please post more information specifically, what HTTP response codes are returned by your calls.